# 405 (method not allowed) when # remove from URL in AngularJS with WebApi

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am creating an application using angular js with web api as service, when i run the application i get the # in URL. In order to remove the # from the URL, we need to add the below like in angular config, almost all suggested to add,

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

so i have added like this, as you can see below..

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function (function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {) {
        stateProvider
          .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            controller: "homeController",
            templateUrl: "/Modules/Views/home.html"
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
```

then i have also added the base tag inside the head tag in index(master) file, as shown below,

```
<base href="/" />
```

and using the `ui-sref` for redirecting in anchor tags, like this

```
<a ui-sref="login">Login</a>
```

When i did this much, i get HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found when i reload/refresh the page, then and i have found someone had suggested to add the below code in web.config,

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
     <rules> 
      <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />                                 
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

When i add this and refresh it works fine, but i get error when i try to login, i get `405 error` as shown below, which means my WepApi services are not working. I am unable to login into application using `/token` of WebApi as you can see in below image.

[image]

But when i remove the code added in web.config then WebApi services works fine, but the problem is, again when i reload i get 404 error, if i remove the code added in Web.Config

Anyone can please help me out in this.

Thanks in adv..

Comment: Upload the method in WebAPI that you are trying to hit. The method you are routing to does not accept HTTP/POST.

Comment: I am not using any method, I am unable to get into application itself. As we know using WebApi `token` we get the access token, I had kept the break point in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method, but it does not hit that break point too. Here is the code in Startup.Auth.cs
`TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14)`

Comment: Ok so you are using ASP.Net Identity. Is that your entire OAuth Server options configuration? I don't see AllowInseucreHttp = true. Your request is not using SSL.

Comment: Yeah, It is also there.. I have not copied. `TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
 AllowInsecureHttp = true`

Comment: Are you hosting web api in IIS? Take a look at your handler settings, https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications.

Comment: You can also turn tracing on in IIS and see what module is being caught.

Comment: No, Whenever i add the above code mentioned in wen.config, i get 405 error. Even i get the same 405  error from fiddler. When i remove that rewrite url code it works fine.

Comment: Try adding `<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="WebApi/(.*)" negate="true" />` to your url rewrite.

Comment: You do not have state called "login" in your State configuration